# org-bullets sub headings invisible

Tags: org-mode

I apologize for the vague post as I do not know how to debug emacs that well. I will provide as much detail as I can and will update it as questions are asked.

## Problem

So prior to updating some of the fonts on my system org mode showed up properly on my system with `org-bullets`. Here is an example of what it looked like

```
 ◉ Heading 1
   ◎ Sub Heading 1
     blah blah
   ◎ Sub Heading 2
     foo bar
```

But for some reason after some changes all the sub heading bullets disappeared. An example is bellow for what I see. All heading are still bold but you will notice that the bullet "o" is gone.

```
 ◉ Heading 1
     Sub Heading 1
     blah blah
     Sub Heading 2
     foo bar
```

## Debug

Some of the information that I think may help with this issue.

```
 org-bullets-bullet-list
 ("◉" "◎" "⚫" "○" "►" "◇")
```

Comment: Before going further, verify that you see the same problem using `emacs -Q` (no init file). I'm guessing you will, but at least that will let everyone know that the problem is not in your init file. (If you don't see the problem with `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file to find the culprit.)

Comment: So I did try that and it is exactly as I suspected it was purely a font issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was exactly as I had suspected it was a font issue with the variable width font not set properly. The font used did not have the utf-8 characters.

The `org-level-1`, `org-level-2` set fonts were nil leading to the heading fonts not displaying. As an example

```
(custom-theme-set-faces 'co/org-theme
       `(org-level-2 ((t (,@headline ,@co/variable-font-tuple :height 1.1))))
```